# print with row for CSV in python respecting column(header) and row

Tags: python, csv

I would like to export the result of my code in a csv file (exel) and print in it but with respecting the Header,row.

Now it print like a normal text in the exel with no consider the row.

like :

[image: exel]

i would like like this :

[image: what i want]

Any idea to make it possible ?

thanks

```
#Source : http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples
import urllib2
import json
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime#set the time



f =       urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json')

now = datetime.now()
current_year = now.year
current_day = now.day
current_month = now.month
current_hour = now.hour
current_minute = now.minute
current_second = now.second

json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
locations = parsed_json.get('locations', 'Beijing')
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather']

#--- Open the file   + write on it ---

f = open('out.csv','a') 
header = "location,temperature,weather,date\n" 
date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
f.write(header)
f.write(','.join([locations,str(temp_f),weather,date]))
f.write('\n')
f.close()
# --- And Close the file ---
```

after the great help of seth

it print this  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
header = "location\ttemperature\tweather\date\n"
f.write(header)
for i in xrange(len(weather)):
    f.write('\t'.join([locations[i],temp_f[i],weather[i],str(now.day)]))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

or the equivalent with no `for` loop, if you're writing inside the loop you're parsing with.

**edit**: or more explicitly:

```
f = open('out.csv','a') #open in append mode if you're already written some of the file.
header = "location\ttemperature\tweather\date\n" #only write this if you haven't already.
date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " + str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
f.write(header)
f.write('\t'.join([locations,temp_f,weather,date]))
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks seth,have got this issue when i tried your code,'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: That is probably because your `locations` ,`temp_f`, `weather` and `str(now.day)` are not lists of these attributes, but single attributes per location.  Try removing the `for` loop and indexes, it should work then.

Comment: ow i see,now i got error for this line : sequence item 1:expected string.int found for('\t'.join([locations,temp_f,weather,str(now.day)])) sorry i am a little newbi on this..

Comment: It's okay, everyone was new.  There shouldn't be a for loop now, check my edited answer.

Comment: thanks :) still got the same issue for f.write('\t'.join([locations,temp_f,weather,date]))  :( :(

Comment: can you edit your question with the new code that is giving you the error? and, even better, print `locations`, `temp_f`, `weather`, and `date` so that we can see precisely what they are.

Comment: i edit my post ,it should go to take the data of the weather so : clear(today) the temperature etc in headers and row.

Comment: I see, change `temp_f` to `str(temp_f)`

Comment: yeah it print now ! :) but little wrong for the spaces etc.hum i update my post. (very thanks for taking your time to help me) i post the result on my original post

Comment: There should be an option in excel to use tab as a delimiter, if you can't find it then try changing all the `'\t'` s in my code to `','`s, commas may be the native delimiter for excel.

Comment: Thanks it works great, i updated my original post,it works perfectly,thanks for everything and have taking your time for me  :) i take your aswer  + 1 !